# Normalization / Scaling as preprocessing step in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am not sure what is the name of the method exactly but I will describe it and hopefully, someone can label it and amend the question accordingly. Here is the code to create the dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=300,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=4,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=True,
                           shift  = 5,
                          scale = 10)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Feature 1':X[:,0],
                                  'Feature 2':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3':X[:,2],
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})

df.describe()
```

[image]

Let's look at the output of **feature 2** and **feature 4** as an example to explain my point.

Assuming we only have **positive values**, how to make feature 2 and feature 4 between the ranges of 0 to 1 in accordance with the range of the values in their columns.

Let me further illustrate.
Feature 2 and feature 4 min value would change to 0 and max value would be 1. However, from the above, we can see that feature 2 maximum value is around 73 and feature 4 max value is 91. The idea is to represent the change on feature 2, 73 to 71 as a bigger number in the 0 to 1 value, then 91 to 89. Although both have the same difference of change which is "2", but because of their range, the change is more significant in feature 2 in comparison to feature 4 due to the total change.

After the following is done, we would create a new dataset representing the new data.

The idea is to later remove features according to the change of value in relation to the range of the column, rather than the magnitude of change in relation to the whole dataset.

I hope this was not confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, MinMaxScaler

mms = MinMaxScaler()

df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains('Feature')] = mms.fit_transform(df.filter(like='Feature'))
```

yields:

```
In [164]: df
Out[164]:
     Class  Feature 1  Feature 2  Feature 3  Feature 4  Feature 5  Feature 6
0        0   0.416385   0.666981   0.510885   0.530803   0.676278   0.443090
1        0   0.556001   0.473475   0.401624   0.272491   0.376577   0.699309
2        0   0.510970   0.617226   0.603038   0.449458   0.703408   0.388056
3        1   0.674764   0.590244   0.639278   0.203411   0.594984   0.289978
4        0   0.284630   0.707643   0.357078   0.653500   0.641764   0.484258
5        0   0.487175   0.566235   0.469849   0.414133   0.550115   0.550655
6        1   0.425064   0.354257   0.452126   0.625156   0.673901   0.641468
7        0   0.412525   0.617383   0.446962   0.536107   0.651904   0.414641
8        0   0.509887   0.382452   0.511992   0.556738   0.768706   0.291556
9        0   0.580941   0.452781   0.534328   0.326482   0.518002   0.641739
..     ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...        ...
290      0   0.728144   0.151289   0.692940   0.409269   0.834617   0.214392
291      1   0.377372   0.169778   0.405410   0.776607   0.736210   0.732727
292      0   0.519530   0.360764   0.503794   0.530192   0.723015   0.374990
293      0   0.629286   0.444416   0.462688   0.194132   0.374052   0.675573
294      1   0.660195   0.675694   0.675262   0.185723   0.575563   0.364423
295      1   0.322941   0.489876   0.474006   0.746047   0.754077   0.643757
296      0   0.460637   0.500117   0.236784   0.305325   0.240014   0.862539
297      1   0.521527   0.326676   0.430562   0.455950   0.557530   0.616107
298      0   1.000000   0.000000   1.000000   0.213472   0.979327   0.012098
299      1   0.688809   0.602628   0.654906   0.184625   0.599433   0.262852

[300 rows x 7 columns]
```

after scaling:

```
In [166]: df.describe()
Out[166]:
            Class   Feature 1   Feature 2   Feature 3   Feature 4   Feature 5   Feature 6
count  300.000000  300.000000  300.000000  300.000000  300.000000  300.000000  300.000000
mean     0.500000    0.493667    0.563870    0.560114    0.475371    0.679344    0.451538
std      0.500835    0.141253    0.189137    0.162298    0.179086    0.156490    0.176866
min      0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
25%      0.000000    0.408848    0.439482    0.446708    0.344611    0.599389    0.317857
50%      0.500000    0.495316    0.566084    0.557805    0.471282    0.704260    0.457312
75%      1.000000    0.581756    0.695583    0.683460    0.593683    0.785408    0.571726
max      1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000
```

Comment: thank you ! how to amend the code to apply it to all feature attributes(feature 1...feature) without explicitly writing it in the filter part ?

Comment: @Victor, you can prepare a list of feature columns and use it or to split your DF into two - one would contain only features, the second - your target (`Class`)

Comment: so the above just did scaling ? and not normalization right ?

Comment: @Victor, what is your goal?

Comment: my final goal is to see the features that contributed the most to the target variable. That is, I have a column that is range 0 to 5. In that column, a change from 5 to 2 is more valuable to me, than a change from another column which is 90005 to 90002 (even though both changed 3). Therefore, the idea is scale them all between 0 to 1. and see the correlation and mutual info between that features and the  target variables. The total value of the individual column represents how important a change in that value is.

Comment: @Victor, you may want to check [different scalers](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing) and [Normalizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.Normalizer)

Comment: @Victor, usually you can see it after training your classification model - the features with highest and lowest coefficients usually contribute the most

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are looking for the [MinMaxScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html) from the `sklearn.preprocessing` module.

> The [sklearn.preprocessing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing) module includes scaling, centering, normalization, binarization and imputation methods.

If you want to rescale the original data "inplace" (i.e., replace the original values with the rescaled ones) then you can do it like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

scaler = MinMaxScaler(copy=False)
scaler.fit_transform(df['Feature 2'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
scaler.fit_transform(df['Feature 4'].values.reshape(-1, 1))

df[['Feature 2', 'Feature 4']].describe()
```

Output:

```
        Feature 2   Feature 4
count  300.000000  300.000000
mean     0.563870    0.475371
std      0.189137    0.179086
min      0.000000    0.000000
25%      0.439482    0.344611
50%      0.566084    0.471282
75%      0.695583    0.593683
max      1.000000    1.000000
```

Comment: can you please apply it to the above example

Comment: @Victor, that's very easy: `mms = MinMaxScaler(); mms.fit_transform(df.filter(like='Feature'))`

Comment: @MaxU you get a numpy array as an output, how to view it as a dataframe :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below log transformation / normalization technique using the package **ctrl4ai**

This will apply log transformation over the features that are skewed/asymmetric

```
pip install ctrl4ai
from ctrl4ai import preprocessing
preprocessing.log_transform(dataset)
```

```
Usage: [arg1]:[pandas dataframe],[method]=['yeojohnson'/'added_constant']
Description: Checks if the a continuous column is skewed and does log transformation
Returns: Dataframe [with all skewed columns normalized using appropriate approach]
```